# How is the set of displacement operators best called?

Tags: operators, terminology, quantum-optics

Displacement operators $\hat D(x,p), \ \ x,p\in\mathbb{R},$ follow a composition rule
$$D(x,p) D(x',p') = \exp\frac{i(px'-xp')}2 D(x+x',p+p').$$
Because of the extraneous phase factor, the set of all displacements is not a group. I could take a set of all displacements multiplied by all possible phase factors and I believe that would be isomorphic to $U(1) \rtimes \mathbb{R}^2$, but if there was an algebraic name for the kind of object that the set of displacements alone forms, that would suit my purpose better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of all possible elements of the form $e^{i\alpha}D(x,p)$ with $\alpha, x,p \in \mathbb R$ verifying  the commutation relations you wrote in addition to:
$$D(x,p)^* = D(-x,-p)\:,\quad D(0,0)=I$$
is a group and it is called **Heisenberg group**, it is homeomorphic (diffeomorphic)  to $U(1) \times \mathbb R^2$ but not isomorphic as a Lie group. It is a real three-dimensional simply-connected Lie group with Lie algebra generated by three elements, one commuting with the others which, in turn, verify the standard position momentum relation commutations.

The *-algebra of all possible complex linear combinations of elements $D(x,y)$
with $x,p \in \mathbb R$ verifying  the commutation relations you wrote in addition to:
$$D(x,p)^* = D(-x,-p)$$ is called **Weyl *-algebra** (actually there is only one way to equip it with a norm making it a $C^*$algebra.)

The objects $D(x,p)$ are called **Weyl generators**.

Comment: Oh yes, of course :-) I knew Heisenberg Lie algebra and did not realize that this was exactly the group generated thereby (and thus would obviously be called Heisenberg group).

Comment: I edited your second last sentence so that it sounds more like a statement of the uniquenss theorem you're alluding to. Please check sense carefully (i.e. I think you're saying that the norm is unique).

Comment: Thanks Rod, I was a bit sloppy. Indeed the C* norm is unique as you wrote. Bye, Valter

Answer (score 1):

We can realize the [displacement operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator) as

$$\tag{1}\hat{D}(x,p)~=~e^{x\hat{P}+p\hat{X}},$$

where the elements $\hat{X}$, $\hat{P}$ and ${\bf 1}$ generates the [Heisenberg algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heisenberg+Lie+algebra)

$$\tag{2} [\hat{X},\hat{P}]=i{\bf 1}.$$

These elements can be realizes as differential operators in the Schrödinger representation. (See also the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem).) Under operator composition $\circ$, we get a [2-cocycle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16131/2451)

$$\tag{3} \hat{D}(x,p) \circ \hat{D}(x^{\prime},p^{\prime})~=~ e^{\frac{i}{2}(x^{\prime}p-p^{\prime}x)}\hat{D}(x+x^{\prime},p+p^{\prime}), $$

due to a simple special case of the [BCH formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula). The operation composition (3) is associative. The formula for three operators reads

$$\tag{4} \hat{D}(x,p) \circ \hat{D}(x^{\prime},p^{\prime})\circ \hat{D}(x^{\prime\prime},p^{\prime\prime})$$
$$~=~ e^{\frac{i}{2}(x^{\prime}p+x^{\prime\prime}p+x^{\prime\prime}p^{\prime}-p^{\prime}x-p^{\prime\prime}x-p^{\prime\prime}x^{\prime})}
\hat{D}(x+x^{\prime}+x^{\prime\prime},p+p^{\prime}+p^{\prime\prime}). $$

The displacement operators are closely related to the [Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group), cf. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#On_symplectic_vector_spaces) paragraph.